# Is it possible to create a chart based on a single cell that contains two separate numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm currently combining two workbooks and then exporting a comparison of the data there. If I'm exporting a table this leaves me with something like so..

```
+----+---------+
| 1  |    2    |
+----+---------+
| aa | 100     |
| bb | 200 250 |
| cc | 300     |
| dd | 400     |
| ee | 500     |
+----+---------+
```

in B3 200 is the original value, and 250 is the modified value. 
If I have a chart based on this table, obviously it can't interpret the data in B3 as it's now text, not a number. Is there any way of getting a chart to do only take a single value from a cell, or delimiting this in some way?

Comment: In brief: "No".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel charts only work with ready-to-use values, they don't have any ability to parse cells to tweeze out content to plot.

The simple solution is to add a helper column. Extract the value you want to the helper column, then plot the helper column instead of the original one.

An even simpler solution is to just not create the problem in the first place.  Instead of merging a new value into the original cell, put it in a separate cell.  If the new value is what you want to be included in the graph, you could have a new column.  The values in that column could be either the original value or the new value if available. That column would then be ready to plot.

Comment: Hey, cheers for the reply, I'd suggested to the team about extracting the value and creating a hidden cell could perhaps be an answer but none of us felt super comfortable about that. We actually do parse the values in to a original/modified report on a different sheet, so we were debating tying it to that cell instead. But it never quite felt right.

Comment: Alas, we're unable to display the modifications in the sheet they came from without inline comparisons. If we insert a new column in to the sheet we can really screw up the display. Additionally all our comparisons treat inline modifications the same way so we'd have some issues with changing how clients view the info

Comment: Our current workaround is to export an image of the modified chart instead of the chart itself, not a perfect solution as the chart is now non-interactive.

Comment: **"An even simpler solution is to just not create the problem in the first place."** - Yes, this.